# How to change from Yield to return with loop?

Tags: python, graph, depth-first-search, maze

I'm doing a code project about resolving labyrinth, I'm using DFS algorithm to find a path from a starting point to a target point.

I've two sections of code, one with 'Yield' which I'm not authorize to use, and other but it sends a bool, I don't know how to get the path.

The first code:

```
def dfs_paths(self, start, target, path=None):
    if path is None:
        path = [start]
    if start == target:
        yield path
    for next in self.mazegrid.adjacency[start] - set(path):
        yield from self.dfs_paths(next, target, path + [next])
```

My question is: How to change this code from 'Yield' and 'Yield from' to return with loop?

The second code:

```
  def explorepath (self, current, objective, visited_list, path) : 
    
    if current == objective : 
        return True
    if current in visited_list : 
        return False 
    visited_list.append(current)
    path.append(current)
    
    for neighbor in self.mazegrid.successors(current): 
        if self.explorepath(neighbor, objective, visited_list, path) == True : 
            return True
        path.remove(current)
        return False
```

I know that the path is stocked in: path, but I don't know how to get it?

Comment: Please add programming-language tag

Comment: If your question is how to write `dfs_paths` without `yield`, what does `explorepath` have to do with it?

Comment: @mkrieger1 there are two questions !

Comment: You should ask only one question.

Comment: More accurately, make two separate questions. Neither is complete, but let's deal with them separately.

Comment: @mkrieger1 ah sorry ! it's the first time I asked on stackoverflow ! I didn't know !

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.